# difference between Byte constructor and Byte.valueOf() method

Tags: java

```
Byte byte1=new Byte("10");
Byte byte2=Byte.valueOf("10");

System.out.println(byte1);
System.out.println(byte2);
```

Both byte1 and byte2 are printing the same value 10.Then what is the difference between constructor parameterized Byte and valueOf() method.

Comment: I would use a `byte` not a `Byte`.  You should use a primitive where possible unless you have a library which expects an object or you can have `null`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/Byte.java) for byte class in JDK 7 shows this:

(I chose the byte versions instead of the String versions because there is less code, but the idea is exactly the same)

```
public static Byte valueOf(byte b) 
{
    final int offset = 128;
    return ByteCache.cache[(int)b + offset];
}
```

and:

```
public Byte(byte value) 
{
   this.value = value;
}
```

Where the ByteCache is:

```
private static class ByteCache 
{
    private ByteCache(){}

    static final Byte cache[] = new Byte[-(-128) + 127 + 1];

    static 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
            cache[i] = new Byte((byte)(i - 128));
    }
}
```

Basically the constructor version is used to create a brand new one, and the `valueOf` version returns a pre-existing one.  That saves memory because there is only one value for `Byte.valueOf(10)` regardless of the number of times you call it, but if you do `new Byte(10)` then a new value is created for each call to `new`.  Since Bytes are immutable (they have no changeable state) there is no reason to create more than one for any given value.

Comment: Note that in JDK6, `Byte.valueOf(byte)` uses the cache, but `Byte.valueOf(String)` does not! (Just oversight I guess - fixed under http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6480728)

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf%28byte%29) for the `valueOf()` method addresses this:

> If a new Byte instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Byte(byte), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance since all byte values are cached.

Comment: is this mean the valueOf() method give better performance than the parameterized Byte constructor and nothing else........I am in confuse

Comment: @rajeev correct. Namely, you'll save space, since you won't have multiple boxes for the same value floating around.

Answer (score 1):

Byte.valueOf("10") is a static factory method which will return byte object and new Byte("10") is a constructor

Answer (score 1):

`Byte.valueOf()` will return a cached instance.

`new Byte()` always returns a new object.

Answer (score 0):

valueOf() is a static factory method,usually better than new Byte(), effective java item1:***consider static factory methods instead of constructors***. the similar class is Boolean.valueOf(), the TRUE or FALSE is instantiation in static final field.